# Can I get a PHP object to run code if a method is not found?

Tags: php, class, object

I have a master class, `DBAPI` which contains all the interaction with the database. It's not singleton per se, but is designed to only be instantiated once as `$DBAPI`.

When I alter the database, I obviously have to add functions to `DBAPI` to let the site use the new functionality, however, since there are a lot of different actions that can be taken, instead of including everything in a single massive class file, I've split them out by functionality/permission level as traits, and the `DBAPI` class file is dynamically created by adding traits flagged based off of permission level (read only, read-write etc.). Since the only time the file needs to be created is when new traits are added, I only create the class file if it doesn't exist for that specific user permission level, otherwise I use the already generated file. (If there's a better way to do this I'm all ears).

The issue I'm running into now is that if I add some functions in a new trait, the previously generated classes are obviously not aware of it, and I don't find out about that until I try to use the function in the code somewhere and it fails. It's pointless to write wrappers around every single function call made to check if it is a function first- **is there some way to get the `DBAPI` class to do some action if code attempts to access a method it can't find?**

for example, if code calls some function `$DBAPI->newfunction()` $DBAPI handles the exception itself, running some code that will attempt to update itself, which will cause newfunction() to run if it can be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(N. B. This architecture has a really bad code smell.  I'm sure there's a better way to do this.)

PHP classes can implement the [`__call` magic method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) that is used when there is no matching method name.

```
function __call( $name, $arguments ) {
    // Code to run...
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I'm looking for. I don't know what to do about the code architecture though....

Comment: @serakfalcon One option for the architecture would be to use multiple classes, each representing access to some type of item in the database or some level of permission.  You could follow that all the way up to a full-fledged [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping), but you don't necessarily need that.  Possibly more simply, you might create a class with the core database stuff and subclass it for each type of data, then use the subclasses for data access instead of the single monolithic `DBAPI` class.

Comment: OK that's good advice I will have to think about how I could do that. I definitely don't need an ORM for this project, but obviously need something between that and just running the queries directly.